# Object modeling and JSON responses

Tags: json, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to implement a web application with a framework which lets you implement both API and user interface (NextJS). And I'm not sure what the best practices for modeling and Json responses are.

**Considerations**

- In the database the models are stored using foreign keys to reference other objects. There are `many-to-many`, `one-to-many` and `on-to-one` relationships.
- Currently using a programming language that allows interface declaration (TypeScript).
- The interface declarations can be accessed from both front and back ends.
- When parsing a model, which has a foreign key, from the database in the backend (API) I use an instance of an interface which has the foreign key declared as a `string`.
- To the front-end I want to return JSON with nested objects. This is, instead of giving a reference to the object in the foreign key, I want to embed an already retrieved object from the database.

**The problem**
If I want to archive this pattern, I'm forced to declare two interfaces: one with a simple shallow reference (foreign key) and another that allows an ambed object.

Example:
Say I have a Blog Post model: `Post`:

```
interface Post {
    id: string;
    creatorId: string;
}
```

And another User model: `User`:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

So for parsing from the database I'm using the `Post` interface which represents exactly how it's stored in the database.
But if I want to return to the frontend the nested object I should rely on a model similar to:

```
interface PostWithNested {
    id: string;
    creator : User;
}
```

where the `JSON` of this interface will be something like:

```
{
    "id": "X",
    "creator": {
        "id" : "Y",
        "name": "Z";
    },
}
```

Example of the API where the parsing from the database must be done using an interface:

```
...
const postsRepository = getRepository(Post); // has shallow reference
const singlePost : Post = await postsRepository.findById(X);
// Adding nested object
const postWithNested : PostWithNested = {
    id : singlePost.id,
    user : userInstance,
}

res.status(200).json({post : postWithNested }
```

So is there a workaround for not declaring two interfaces that are essentially equal but differ on the reference to its related object?

Comment: You get `userInstance` in a separate call or on the same call as `postsRepository .findById`?

Comment: Assume Im getting it in the same function with a similar approach: `const usersRepo = getRepository(User); const userInstance = await usersRepo.findById(post.creatorId)`

Comment: Hmm if it's in the same function (the response with user data). You just need to use `const singlePost : PostWithNested` would that be enough? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but the point is that I have two interfaces for a single model. One with shallow ref, and another with the nested object. And since I can access both interfaces in either side (front and end), this can lead to confusion

Comment: I think you're looking for optional data in `Post`. This section is not enough for the explanation, so I gave out a possible answer below. We can continue discussing if you feel it's not good enough for your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface `Post` with an optional `creator`. For example

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
interface Post {
    id: string;
    creatorId: string;
    creator?: User; //it will be not populated, if it has no data
}
```

Whenever you receive `creator` data from API, it will be populated automatically. Otherwise, it will be unset always in your `Post` data. You can verify logs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZkG8BQyRywAJgFzLZSgDmA3IcQlBHGOlAJIVVg0gGTIizYcoAfkoBVTNEYBffPlCRYiFLOh5hJXtTqNiyEHAC2ESgcGLlCdCGzIADljCUMTgLw6iZSgBEAKwBADRMouycPIEAjAH4Svj2jugANhAAdGnotAAUrtgAlHYOToVgAOrAYAAWWlAebsg%20BH68wWERrFHcHfHhIj3ilG3EphaBkNhdxv7IAfFMSkkpmOlZOfkV1XUNRUA).

Here is how we integrate it into your code

```
const postsRepository = getRepository(Post);
const singlePost : Post = await postsRepository.findById(X);

res.status(200).json({post : singlePost })
```

Similarly, if you have `one-many` relationship. For example, 1 user has many posts, you will have this interface structure

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    posts?: Post[]; //can keep many posts belong to this user
}
interface Post {
    id: string;
    creatorId: string;
    creator?: User; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for you response. I do like your approach, but looking at the libraries I'm using for Object relational mapping from the database, they reflect the properties of the interface in the tables/documents. So if I add a new property, it will be reflected in the database, even if undefined

Comment: But lets assume that properties which are not populated dont add to the database. Wouldnt this force the client to check whether the property was populated or not on each access?

Comment: I just verified the change here (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZkG8BQyRywAJgFzLZSgDmA3IcQlBHGOlAJIVVg0gGTIizYcoAfkoBVTNEYBffPlCRYiFLOh5hJXtTqNiyEHAC2ESgcGLlCdCGzIADljCUMTgLw6iZSgBEAKwBADRMouycPIEAjAH4Svj2jugANhAAdGnotAAUrtgAlHYOToVgAOrAYAAWWlAebsg+BH68wWERrFHcHfHhIj3ilG3EphaBkNhdxv7IAfFMSkkpmOlZOfkV1XUNRUA)
`creator` is not populated if we never set it. I think it won't affect your object relational mapping. To be more sure, could you let me know which library you're using for object relational mapping?

Comment: `Wouldnt this force the client to check whether the property was populated or not on each access` yes indeed, but we can do a simple check with `?`. For example, `post.creator?.name` won't throw errors if `creator` is not there

Comment: The library I'm using is fireORM https://fireorm.js.org/#/ . Setting a model with conditional properties seem to work, going to try and get back with results ;)

Comment: @EzequielGimenez I'm not sure about your whole setup, but I found these 2 documents: Document Reference (https://fireorm.js.org/#/Read_Data?id=search-by-document-reference) and Subcollection (https://fireorm.js.org/#/Subcollections) that would be useful for your case.